# Composer.json update error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Faced such a problem when updating the Compressor. Spent several hours, but I could not solve the problem. Help me please.

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.32
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.31
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.30
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.8.29
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.29
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.28
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.27
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.26
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.25
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.24
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.23
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.22
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.21
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.20
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.19
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.18
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.17
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.16
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.15
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.14
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.13
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.12
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.11
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.10
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.8
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.7
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.6
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.5
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.4
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.3
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.2
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.1
- doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.0.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle 
^3.3|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v3.3.0, v3.3.1, 
v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.1
3, v3.3.14, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, 
v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2].
- doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.0.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle 
^3.3|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v3.3.0, v3.3.1, 
v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.1
3, v3.3.14, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, 
v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2].
- doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.0.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle 
^3.3|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v3.3.0, v3.3.1, 
v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.1
3, v3.3.14, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, 
v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.3.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v4.0.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v4.0.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- symfony/framework-bundle v4.0.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.0].
- Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.8.* -> satisfiable by 
symfony/symfony[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, 
v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18
, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, 
v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, 
v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8
, v2.8.9].
- Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.0.* -> 
satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2].
```

When developing my project, I have to update all the installed bands, but I can not do it. This error occurs during the upgrade and installation. I can not also install new bundles, because this error does not allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project requires a version of doctrine-fixtures-bundle which itself requires symfony/framework-bundle of version 3.3.*, but this framework bundle is not compatible with symfony 2.8. So you either need to upgrade symfony, or change your composer.json to require an older version of doctrine-fixtures-bundle which is compatible with your version of symfony.

Take a look at the various versions available to find a suitable version for your project. 2.4.1 looks like it might be usable - https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle